# Golang Combine Error got unexpected github.com/pkg/errors.Is And github.com/pkg/errors.Cause

Tags: go, error-handling

I have dilema for combine error either using `github.com/pkg/errors.Wrap` or `fmt.Errorf`.

If I use `github.com/pkg/errors.Wrap`, I got unexpected when using `github.com/pkg/errors.Is`.

If I use `fmt.Errorf`, I got unexpected when using `github.com/pkg/errors.Cause`.

I hope this playground is clear enough. https://go.dev/play/p/5Y77Yxg51jF

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

var err1 = errors.New("err1")
var err2 = errors.New("err2")

func foo() error {
    return err1
}

func bar() error {
    return err1
}

func main() {
    errFoo := foo()
    errFoo = errors.Wrap(errFoo, err2.Error())
    fmt.Println(errFoo)                  // got "err2: err1", expected
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(errFoo, err1)) // got "true", expected
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(errFoo, err2)) // got "false", want true
    fmt.Println(errors.Cause(errFoo))    // got "err1", expected

    fmt.Println("*********")

    errBar := bar()
    errBar = fmt.Errorf("%w: %w", err2, errBar)
    fmt.Println(errBar)                  // got "err2: err1", expected
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(errBar, err1)) // got "true", expected
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(errBar, err2)) // got "true", expected
    fmt.Println(errors.Cause(errBar))    // got "err2: err1", want err1
}
```

Comment: Do not use github.com/pkg/errors. It's that simple. It is an archived project for a reason: It offers nothing you couldn't get from the stdlib package errors.

Comment: In the first section err2 is not part of the error chain. You just wrapped some error with the string that happens to be returned by err2.Error(), but err2 itself isn't used. In the second section your expectations are not justified either. fmt.Errorf with multiple %w verbs returns an error implementing `Unwrap() []error`.  That's not something errors.Cause looks for, as documented (nor errors.Unwrap, FWIW). What is your question?